# How to remap coc.nvim autocomplete key?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, coc.nvim, neovim

I was trying to change my coc.nvim autocomplete key, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387663/how-to-remap-coc-vim-autocomplete-key) question in Stack Overflow, but the guy who answer this question doesn't explain really good how to customize it as you want, so I will explain it to help the NeoVim users that are racking the brain for this as I was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

If you want to bind <kbd>Tab</kbd> for autocompletion, paste this in your .vimrc or init.vim

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <tab> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "\<C-g>u\<TAB>"
inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> "\<c-g>u\<CR>"
```

### Detailed answer

So, you have to make 2 insert mode remaps, in this case I will remap my completion to <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <tab> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "\<C-g>u\<TAB>"
```

Obs: If you want to bind other key to autocomplete:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> [the key that you want to autocomplete] pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "\<C-g>u\<TAB>"
```

Now, CoC will autocomplete with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key too, but <kbd>Enter</kbd> is also autocompleting, I want to bind <kbd>Enter</kbd> by just be <kbd>Enter</kbd>, not an autocompletion key.

In VimScript <kbd>Enter</kbd> is represented by `<cr>`

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> "\<c-g>u\<cr>"
```

Obs:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> [this is the current autocompletion key] "\<c-g>u\[this is the bind that I am giving to the key]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [example vim configuration](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim#example-vim-configuration) gives some very useful tips for COC.

But specifically for you this is relevant:

```
" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate.
" NOTE: There's always complete item selected by default, you may want to enable
" no select by `"suggest.noselect": true` in your configuration file.
" NOTE: Use command ':verbose imap <tab>' to make sure tab is not mapped by
" other plugin before putting this into your config.
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) :
      \ CheckBackspace() ? "\<Tab>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(1) : "\<C-h>"

" Make <CR> to accept selected completion item or notify coc.nvim to format
" <C-g>u breaks current undo, please make your own choice.
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"

function! CheckBackspace() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction
```